# Finding a point on the line joining two points in Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a point A with coordinates (a,b) ; a point B with coordinates (c,d) , I want to find a point C's coordinate (x,y) ,with C lying on the line joining A and B and C is at a distance Dist from point A.
[**This is the representation**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23755950/fucaaaaa.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use Linear Interpolation.  You can interpolate both the x and y coordinate independently.  Let $\alpha = Dist/\sqrt{(c-a)^2+(d-b)^2}$.  Then the interpolated point is given by:

$$x = a + \alpha(c-a)$$

and

$$y = b + \alpha(d-b)$$

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use linear interpolation. You can interpolate both the $x$ and $y$ coordinate independently. Let a = dist (c-a)2+(d-b)2.Then then the interpolated point is given by:

$$x=a+a(c-a)$$

Comment: Please edit your inline equation using the proper markup: this way it is not too clear and it looks like two different objects are called with the same name *a*.